# How to unnest a column with double and character values into one character column?

Tags: r, dplyr, compare

I am trying to build a report with comparisons from 2 data frames. I am using the `comparedf` from the `arsenal` package. The problem is that to be able to export it to an excel file I need to unnest the column, but because I have double and characters on the same column, it is not letting me unnest the column.

Here is the example, suppose I have the following data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var2 = c("A","B","C","A","B"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d","e"),
                  var =c(1,3,4,2,5),
                  var2 = c("C","A","C","A","B"))
```

Then using comparedf I am generating another data frame with the comparison of non-matching values:

```
library(arsenal)
summary(comparedf(df1, df2, by="id"))

Table: Differences detected

var.x   var.y   id   values.x   values.y    row.x   row.y
------  ------  ---  ---------  ---------  ------  ------
var     var     b    2          3               2       2
var     var     c    3          4               3       3
var     var     d    4          2               4       4
var2    var2    a    A          C               1       1
var2    var2    b    B          A               2       2
```

The columns values.x and values.y are two nested lists, thus I try to capture this table with the following codes:

```
vec1 <- summary(comparedf(df1, df2, by="id"))
library(tidyr)
diftable <- vec1$diffs.table |> unnest(cols = c(values.x, values.y))
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Can't combine `x[[1]]` <double> and `x[[4]]` <character>.
```

How can I force these two columns to unnest into one character column?

Comment: Perhaps convert both to character first, something like `vec1$diffs.table %>% mutate(across(values.x:values.y, as.character)) %>% unnest(cols = c(values.x, values.y))`?

Comment: Thank you so much, Jon! Code works!

Comment: Why don't you put it as an answer so I can accept it and mark as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the two columns to character so they can then be combined into a homogenous atomic vector.

```
vec1$diffs.table %>% 
  mutate(across(values.x:values.y, as.character)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(values.x, values.y))
```